# ArcGis online app - editor stopped working

Tags: editing, arcgis-online

I am trying to use ArcGIS Online.
I have a web map application but all of a sudden I am unable to create points when editing.

I've tested the map service and editing via arcmap without any issues.

When I do try and create a point I get the following error in the google chrome console:

```
Error: Unable to complete operation.

at Error (native)

at Object.g.load (http://js.arcgis.com/3.16/init.js:1042:343)

at http://js.arcgis.com/3.16/init.js:181:69

at c (http://js.arcgis.com/3.16/init.js:66:221)

at d (http://js.arcgis.com/3.16/init.js:66:10)

at resolve.callback (http://js.arcgis.com/3.16/init.js:67:350)

at c (http://js.arcgis.com/3.16/init.js:66:436)

at d (http://js.arcgis.com/3.16/init.js:66:10)

at resolve.callback (http://js.arcgis.com/3.16/init.js:67:350)

at http://js.arcgis.com/3.16/init.js:185:300
```

- the first time I examined the console error log I noticed dojo errors (referenced back
  to the arcgis.com site)

I've eliminated proxy and firewall issues and I have tried to edit now on three different
browsers.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: It appears that this was a historically corrupt feature layer.  We have recreated the layer from scratch and all appears to be working now ...

Answer (score 0):

I changed my script from 3.11 to 3.16 and lost editing capabilities, once I switched it back they started working again.  I was going to look into the difference between 3.11 and 3.16 to see what was going on.